# jQuery - binding event to named function does not work?

Tags: jquery, function, binding

I tried binding a named function to a form submit event.
At first, I tried binding it to an anonymous function and it worked:

```
jQuery("#form").submit(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            alert("event");
            var reqType = jQuery(this).find('input[name="requestType"]').val();
            alert("requestType:"+reqType);
        });
```

And it worked fine.
But when I used a named function:

```
         //inside jQuery(document).ready()            
         jQuery("#form").submit(processForm(event));

         //defined outside jQuery(document).ready()
         function processForm(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var reqType = jQuery(this).find('input[name="requestType"]').val();
            alert("request type: "+reqType);
        }
```

Not only does the function did not work as I hoped it would, the alert() would just fire when the page is refresh while the form is not submitted. What could be the cause of this and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the function by reference, without brackets:

```
jQuery("#form").submit(processForm);
```